# ReactJS: Uncaught ReferenceError: [function] not defined, July 2017

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

Attempting to turn a JSON file into an array, then randomly selecting 5 items from it.

I *think* the issue is my render/return statement at the bottom of ImageContainer.js, but I'm a ReactJS n00b, so it could be anything.

Any help or advice is greatly appreciated.

**Console Error**

```
compiled.js:31562 Uncaught ReferenceError: selectImages is not defined
  at ImageContainer.render (compiled.js:31562)
  at compiled.js:20195
  at measureLifeCyclePerf (compiled.js:19475)
  at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._renderValidatedComponentWithoutOwnerOrContext (compiled.js:20194)
  at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._renderValidatedComponent (compiled.js:20221)
  at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount (compiled.js:19761)
  at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (compiled.js:19657)
  at Object.mountComponent (compiled.js:4009)
  at ReactDOMComponent.mountChildren (compiled.js:24150)
  at ReactDOMComponent._createInitialChildren (compiled.js:21126)
```

**ImageContainer.js** - pulls img info from a .JSON file, randomly selects 5 to render

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Image } from './Image';

export class ImageContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.numImages = 5;

    this.state = {
      data: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    $.ajax({
      url: '../app/data/namegame-data.json',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
        this.setState({data: data});
      }.bind(this),
      error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        console.error('#GET Error', status, err.toString());
      }.bind(this)
    });
  }

  shuffleArray(array) {
    let i = array.length - 1;
    for (; i > 0; i--) {
      const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
      const temp = array[i];
      array[i] = array[j];
      array[j] = temp;
    }
    return array;
  }

  selectImages({ data }) {
    const shuffledImages = shuffleArray(images);
    return (
      shuffledImages.map((data, idx) => {
        for (let i = 0; i < this.numImages; i++) {
            if (this.state.data.length > 0) {
                return <Image key={idx} name={data.name} src={data.src} />;
            }
        }
      })
    );
  }

  render() {
    return {selectImages};
  }
}
```

**Image.js** - just the image HTML

```
import React from 'react';

export class Image extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const key = this.props.id;
        const name = this.props.name;
        const src = this.props.src;
        return (
            <picture>
                <img id="pic-template" className="pic" src="{src}" name="{name}" key="id" />
            </picture>
        );
    }
}
```

**[Main].js** - most of the HTML is here, just including the import bits

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { ImageContainer } from './ImageContainer';

export default class NameGame extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      ...
      <div id="images-wrap">
          <ImageContainer />
      </div>
      ...
    );
  }
}
```

**Dependencies**

```
{
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^0.28.4",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.3",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
    "style-loader": "^0.18.2",
    "webpack": "^2.2.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.5.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think "this" is where it goes wrong ;):

selectImages is part of the ImageContainer class, 
meaning the function is scoped within this Class, so it should be this.selectImages

In the render you call selectimages

```
render() {
    return {this.selectImages()}; <-- its a function so u should call it as a function
}
```

Remember selectimage should return a react component, but if it will return a array of items that
react will render you should wrap it, you cannot pas multiple react elements to render

so you should something like

```
render() {
    return (
        <div> <-- give render 1 react component wrapping the multiple components 
            {this.selectImages()}; <-- its a function so u should call it as a function
        </div>
    )
}
```

selectImages({ data }) <-- where is it getting data from ? i don't think data is needed , only if u gonna pass { data: 'whatever' } to the function

```
shuffledImages.map((data, idx) => { 
 data will be the items from the shuffledImages array
})


const shuffledImages = shuffleArray(images); should be ->
const shuffledImages = this.shuffleArray(images);
```

about your other question

```
shuffleArray() {
  (array) <-- u are mutating the data from the state, when u passed it to the function, u should only change state with setState.

     use another shuffle function where u dont mutate the data ,use concat or es6 spread operator [ ...data ] etc .
```

read: "[Correct modification of state arrays in ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26253351/correct-modification-of-state-arrays-in-reactjs)"

}

```
    selectImages() {
      const shuffledImages = this.shuffleArray(this.state.data); <-- u dont have to pass this.state.data, to the function ,it is accessable within shufflarray -> const shuffledImages = this.shuffleArray();

      return (
          shuffledImages.map((data, idx) => {
            for (let i = 0; i < this.numImages; i++) {
                return <Image key={idx} name={this.state.data.name} src={this.state.data.src} />;
            }
          })
      );
    }
```

if ur ajax call fails array is undefined. and u cannot call length on undefined. (thats what the error says)- about ur call

u need to tell ur ajax call what to do, is it a post or get?
add a 'type' (it should be type: 'get', )

or use the shorthand (i see u are using jquery)

```
$.getJSON('whateverjson file.json').done(function(response) {
    console.log("Success");
}).fail(function() {
    console.log("Error");
});
```

About the data ->

```
u should parse the json setstate({ data: JSON.parse(data) }) or setstate({ data: $.parseJSON(data) });
```

I must say using jquery, in combination with react, is not something i should recommend, jquery is mostly used for dom manipulation, react uses its virtual dom, and to include the whole jquery library for only the ajax requests is a waste.

try 'fetch' <==

PS look into https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html (react docs)

Its also best to pass results of api calls to the component as props, but u will figure that out once u dive into the docs! i hope this helps u, good luck m8

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Definitely a few steps closer. The error is now: *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined* In addition to making your change and adding a few more "this." prefixes,  I changed componentDidMount() to componentWillMount(), which loads, but the ajax call does not succeed.

Comment: Further reading indicates that componentDidMount() is correct, but the JSON may *not* be getting parsed into anything usable - continuing to hack at this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated (mostly) working version of ImageContainer.js, which incorporates Danillo's changes and solves the array problem that followed. The issues were mainly related to missing "this." and "this.state."

**ImageContainer.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Image } from './Image';

export class ImageContainer extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.numImages = 5;

        this.state = {
          data: []
        };
    }

    componentWillMount() {
      $.ajax({
          url: './app/data/namegame-data.json',
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function(data) {
            this.setState({data: data});
          }.bind(this),
          error: function(xhr, status, err) {
            console.error('#GET Error', status, err.toString());
          }.bind(this)
        });
    }

    shuffleArray(array) {
      let i = array.length - 1;
      for (; i > 0; i--) {
        const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        const temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = temp;
      }
      return array;
    }

    selectImages() {
      const shuffledImages = this.shuffleArray(this.state.data);
      return (
          shuffledImages.map((data, idx) => {
            for (let i = 0; i < this.numImages; i++) {
                return <Image key={idx} name={this.state.data.name} src={this.state.data.src} />;
            }
          })
      );
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.selectImages()};
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i quickly changed ur code at 00:45 :D, but try something like this, explenation in my other answer. gl!

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Image } from './Image';

export class ImageContainer extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          data: [],
          numImages: 5
        };
    }

    componentWillMount() {
      $.ajax({
          url: './app/data/namegame-data.json',
          dataType: 'json',
          type: 'get',
          success: function(data) {
            this.setState({data: JSON.parse(data) });
          }.bind(this),
          error: function(xhr, status, err) {
            console.error('#GET Error', status, err.toString());
          }.bind(this)
        });
    }

    randomPickFromArray() {
      // * as asked: " Attempting to turn a JSON file into an array, then randomly selecting 5 items from it. "

      // lets not shuffle, and just random pick 5 items from array,
      const { data, numImages } = this.state;
      const arr = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < numImages; i++) {
        arr.push(data[Math.floor(Math.random() * data.length)]);
      }
      return arr;
    }

    selectImages() {
      const shuffledImages = this.randomPickFromArray();
      return shuffledImages.map((item, idx) => <Image key={idx} name={item.name} src={item.src} />);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.selectImages()};
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```